# How to call KO js functions outside the template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, knockoutjs

Is it possible to access  variable `addressConverter` from custom js file.

Filename: `Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address.js`

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter'
    ],
    function(addressList, addressConverter) {
        "use strict";
        return function(addressData) {
            var address = addressConverter.formAddressDataToQuoteAddress(addressData);
            var isAddressUpdated = addressList().some(function(currentAddress, index, addresses) {
                if (currentAddress.getKey() == address.getKey()) {
                    addresses[index] = address;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
            if (!isAddressUpdated) {
                addressList.push(address);
            } else {
                addressList.valueHasMutated();
            }
            return address;
        };
    }
);
```

I am trying to add custom temporary shipping address, If customer selects temporary shipping address then store pickup shipping method will display.

If customer selects any other shipping address then other shipping methods will display except store pickup method.

Can any one help how to do this.